# NSBackgroundColorAttributeName doesn't seem to work on iOS 10.3

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

We display a label in our apps which contains attributed text and some highlighting color. To achieve this, we use the following code which used to work:

```
let paddedLineAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: paddedLine, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : newFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : color])
```

But after upgrading one of our test devices to iOS 10.3, the specified background color for the label is not taking effect anymore. Instead, it was using a transparent background color making the label invisible as we are using a white text color which is the same color as the parent view.

I suspect that the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` is the culprit but the official API Reference remains unchanged - https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsbackgroundcolorattributename

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try this suggestion - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try it for now and see if that's a workaround we can do for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from @schystz comment:

Adding `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 0` resolves the issue.

```
let paddedLineAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: paddedLine, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : newFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : color, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 0])
```