# iOS 10.3: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is not rendered if applied to a sub range of NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

A strikethrough (single, double, ...) added as attribute to an instance of `NSMutableAttributedString` is not rendered if the apply range is not the whole string range.

This happens using `addAttribute(_ name: String, value: Any, range: NSRange)`,  `insert(_ attrString: NSAttributedString, at loc: Int)`, `append(_ attrString: NSAttributedString)`, ...

Broken by Apple in early iOS 10.3 betas, and not fixed in 10.3 final.

Credit:
https://openradar.appspot.com/31034683

Comment: Fixed in iOS 10.3.2 beta 2

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 10.3.2 current release, but it works in iOS 11.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding a `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`, as explained [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72643), to the attributed string brings back the strikethrough line. Overriding `drawText:in:` can be slow especially on Collection View or Table View Cells.

Answer (score 93):

Setting the baseline offset seems to fix it:

```
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@2 range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```

This is a known [bug](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/31034683) in iOS 10.3

Comment: This also works for superscript and subscript attributes.

Comment: It is working but I have a doubt "NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName" default value is zero. Then why we need to Set the value.

Comment: It's clearly a bug so it must have some sort of rendering side effect

Answer (score 14):

Found a workaround for our specific scenario (we don't specify any styling with UILabel's properties, but all with `NSAttributedString` attributes):

```
/// This UILabel subclass accomodates conditional fix for NSAttributedString rendering broken by Apple in iOS 10.3
final class PriceLabel: UILabel {

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        guard let attributedText = attributedText else {
            super.drawText(in: rect)
            return
        }

        if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
            attributedText.draw(in: rect)
        } else {
            super.drawText(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: if you mix UILabel's styling properties with `NSAttributedString` attributes, you should think of creating a new attributed string before rendering, apply UILabel's styling on it and then re-apply all `attributedText`'s attributes over it.

Comment: This as been killing me all day, so glad you found a solution

Comment: For what it's worth, I've also found that for iOS 10.3 release, attributed strings are not rendered with the font style set on the UILabel property. So for example, it is not enough to specify the UILabel's font type if you are using attributed Text property. You must include the desired font via NSFontAttributeName as an attribute

Comment: when i override drawText function as you said, it will ignore all label style i gave in storyboard (alignment, font, color). is there anyway to cast all these styles to NSMutableAttributedString's attribute?

Comment: @Mohammadalijf that what I put into the note underneath my answer - read them from the label's properties and reapply as `NSAttributedString` attributes.

Answer (score 10):

swift 3 working code tested with 10.3

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "₹3500")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
productPriceLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Answer (score 10):

## Swift 4

```
let text = "Hello World"
let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle,
                            value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                            range: textRange)
myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: Great! Had to spent almost an hour to find out those keys `NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle`, etc.

Comment: The point is use ```NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue``` not ```NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle```.

Answer (score 4):

Its a bug known to Xcode 8.3 (8E3004b) / iOS 10.3, with this workaround NO extra line of code is need, just add `[NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:0]` when declaring `NSMutableAttributedString()`

```
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: YOUR_STRING_HERE, attributes: [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : 0])

// Now if you add the strike-through attribute to a range, it will work
attrStr.addAttributes([
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24),
    NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 1
], range: NSRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5 `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` changed with `kCTBaselineOffsetAttributeName` and will change every new version.