# NSMutableAttributedString not working in tableviewcell with a specific range

Tags: ios, swift3, nsattributedstring, ios10.3

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub) but didn't solve my problem.

I have a `tableview` in ViewController , `tableviewcell` have a label. I want to set `attributedString` with `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`. If i am setting complete string as a strikethrough it works **but** if i am setting as partial it doesn't works.

> Below code for success result

```
let strOriginalPrice = "my price"
let strdiscountedPrice = "discounted price"
let strPrice = strOriginalPrice+" "+strdiscountedPrice

let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: strPrice)
 attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

cell.lblPrice.attributedText = attributeString
```

> Below code not working

```
let attributedDiscunt: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: strPrice)
            attributedDiscunt.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value:2, range: NSMakeRange(0, strOriginalPrice.characters.count-1))

cell.lblPrice.attributedText = attributedDiscunt
```

Comment: iOS 10.3 ? If that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub/43359207

Comment: Yep, this is a bug in iOS 10.3. Attributes no longer work for a range of your string, only for the whole string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10.3: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is not rendered if applied to a sub range of NSMutableAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub)

Comment: @Maddy Since the issue is in fact only reproducible on iOS10.3 due to an iOS Bug, and there is already another question on SO which point it out (in opposition to the answers below which doesn't explain that), it's better in any case to mark the question as duplicate and redirect so to the previous one.

Comment: @Maddy And this isn't showed in his code, and what's the real difference then with Lion's or yours answers. Didn't you followed the indication from that other question (adding baseline)?

Comment: Both answers have an unfortunate typo, so obviously copy-pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
   let strOriginalPrice = "my price"
    let strdiscountedPrice = "discounted price"
    let strPrice = strOriginalPrice+" "+strdiscountedPrice

 //        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: strPrice)
//        attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    let attributedDiscunt: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: strPrice)
    attributedDiscunt.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value:2, range: NSMakeRange(0, strOriginalPrice.characters.count-1))
    attributedDiscunt.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, strOriginalPrice.characters.count-1))


    cell.lblPrice.attributedText = attributedDiscunt
```