# NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName Not working if append with another string or attributed string

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, concatenation, nsattributedstring

Well, it is very strange for me that, `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` doesn't working if I concatenate/ append two `NSMutableAttributedString` for a label.

```
let partTwo: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "4450")

        partTwo.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, partTwo.length))

        cell.lbl11.attributedText = partTwo
```

Above code working perfect, but if I do bellow code:

```
let partOne: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "WAS $")
        let partTwo: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "4450")
        partTwo.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, partTwo.length))
        let concate = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: partOne)
        concate.append(partTwo)
        cell.lbl11.attributedText = concate


NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName doesn't working.
```

I needs like below image in one single label. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Because its property overrides with new attributed string. So again make it strikeThrough

Comment: This question has a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/