# Failing to create a strikethrough on part of the text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I am trying to create a strikethrough effect on part of a UILabel text, so fat without success. I have noticed that I can create this effect on ALL the text, but not just part of it. Here's what I have

```
let text = "\(20.4$) \(On Rush Hour)"
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "20.4$")
attrStr.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName,
                     value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                     range: range)
self.originalPriceLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

Now, if I only replace

```
let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "20.4$")
```

with

```
let range = (text as NSString).range(of: text)
```

I see the strikethrough. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug in iOS10.3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub/43359207 ?

Comment: Another way is to make two attributed strings, one with strike through and other without it and then concatenate them .. and set them to your label ..

Comment: that worked @Larme, thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10.3: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is not rendered if applied to a sub range of NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub)

Comment: iOS 11 seems to handle this fine.